# Mapbox GL JS version v0.41.1 not working

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to make heat-maps using map box, currently I am printing circles which work with v0.39.1.

When I change to v0.41.1 the code doesn't work and throws error

```
mapdata.js:78 Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined
```

Please help! Thanks

Edit: I just saw on the website that it is not yet supported, nevertheless, is there a way it can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 0.41.1 — the current release is 0.41.0. (Releases are listed [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/releases), and the current release is always reflected in the script/CSS tags in the [official examples](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/)). Heatmaps are supported as of 0.41.0.